# Use ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 to login user

Tags: c#, identityserver4, saml-2.0, adfs, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am trying to implement SAML2.0 authentication using IdentityServer4 and ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 library.

The first step is to login via the LDAP connection and this part worked well and i get user claims.

Next step is to integrate login using AD FS

I followed principally this tutorial

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp

The Saml configuration code is below

```
services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(saml2Configuration =>
{
    saml2Configuration.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(saml2Configuration.Issuer);

    var entityDescriptor = new EntityDescriptor();
    entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(Configuration["Saml2:IdPMetadata"]));
    if (entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor != null)
    {
        saml2Configuration.SingleSignOnDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices.First().Location;
        saml2Configuration.SignatureValidationCertificates.AddRange(entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SigningCertificates);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("IdPSsoDescriptor not loaded from metadata.");
    }
});

services.AddSaml2();
```

After server redirection and before displaying the Idp login page i have an error "certificate are not properly configured at application end"

This is the first time that I deal with SAML protocol. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit :** The error is on the AD FS Side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more information, the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 [documentation](https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2) and a [ASP.NET Core sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCore).

I'm in doubt where you see the error. Is it at the IdentityServer4 application or in AD FS?

The configuration you show read the AD FS metadata and set up the IdP configuration. You also need to load the relying party configuration.

```
services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(Configuration.GetSection("Saml2"));
```

and set the relying party signing certificate e.g., like this

```
saml2Configuration.SigningCertificate = CertificateUtil.Load(AppEnvironment.MapToPhysicalFilePath(
            Configuration["Saml2:SigningCertificateFile"]),
```

The configuration together

```
services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(Configuration.GetSection("Saml2"));
services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(saml2Configuration =>
{
    saml2Configuration.SigningCertificate = CertificateUtil.Load(AppEnvironment.MapToPhysicalFilePath(
        Configuration["Saml2:SigningCertificateFile"]), Configuration["Saml2:SigningCertificatePassword"]);
    saml2Configuration.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(saml2Configuration.Issuer);

var entityDescriptor = new EntityDescriptor();
    entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(Configuration["Saml2:IdPMetadata"]));
if (entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor != null)
    {
        saml2Configuration.SingleSignOnDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices.First().Location;
        saml2Configuration.SingleLogoutDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleLogoutServices.First().Location;
        saml2Configuration.SignatureValidationCertificates.AddRange(entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SigningCertificates);
    }
else
    {
        throw new Exception("IdPSsoDescriptor not loaded from metadata.");
    }
});
services.AddSaml2();
```

**Remark**

To solve a situation like yours I have created [FoxIDs](https://www.foxids.com/docs) which support OpenID Connect and can be connected to an AD FS with SAML 2.0. FoxIDs handles the conversion between OpenID Connect and SAML 2.0. Actually, FoxIDs also use the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 library.

Comment: thank you for reply. I have test this changes and I have another error message on ITfoxtec *No RSA Private Key present in Signing Certificate or missing private key read credentials*.

Comment: The certificate you are trying to use for signing only contain the public key. You need a certificate including the private key. E.g., a .pfx file.